# Destroy or finish an Activity from tabcontent in TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have an app where I've used Tab Host to hold multiple activities on a single screen. This is how I'm adding tabs to the Tab Host.

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, myLayout, false);
tab1.setIndicator(view);
tab1.setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClass1.class));
tabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

In my custom view for indicator, there is a close button which is supposed to close that tab and the activity associated with it. Here is how I successfully removed the view from Tab-Widget when the close button is clicked on the tab.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().removeViewAt(index_of_tab);
```

This code removes the tab, but it does not remove the activity that was started in the FrameLayout (tabcontent), and it results in showing this Activity again when opened different tab with different Acvitiy.

For example, once I opened a tab with activity **MyClass1** and closed it. Again I opened a new tab with activity **MyClass2**, but the old activity **MyClass1** appears again instead of **MyClass2**.

Am I doing it wrong ? If it is wrong what is the correct way to close the tab along with the activity associated with it ?

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use a `TabHost` in one of my projects and as far as the tab closing goes, I gave it up and did it the brute way, as seems that `TabHost` is a bit tricky when closing tabs.

So I ended up calling `.clearAllTabs()` and restoring just the tabs I wanted to keep. The whole thing is even worse when you realize that once you've set your `TabHost.TabSpec` object, you cannot retrieve it, there's not any `getTabSpec()` method over a tab or similar, so I finally ended up declaring an `ArrayMap<String, TabHost.TabSpec>` and each time I add a tab, I also save it in that Map.

This way each time I have to call `clearAllTabs()` on the `TabHost`, I just have to iterate over the map and call `.addTab()` on each tab I want to keep with the `TabHost.TabSpec` as parameter (and of course, also remove the one I want to clear from the map).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nKn

Did it successfully closed (finished) the Activity associated with the tab which was closed ? Adding the new from the Map will start the activity again, or it will just resume it ?

Comment: Yes, it closed it because when you call `.clearAllTabs()` it will destroy any content inside it, and it won't start the `Activity` again because you have saved its state in the Map (the `TabHost.TabSpec` will actually save the content of the tab, so when you call `.addTab()` you're just making it visible on the tab, but it has always been there).

Comment: Great !! I am now trying with creating new class which extends TabHost and it will have those missing functions which I want, to remove tabs with their contents. Will get back with results. Thank you very much.